# How can I stop the browser from url-encoding for react js form for POST data values with password field value included with #

Tags: javascript, java, c#, reactjs, jquery-ui

I wanted to stop URL encoding for reactjs form password filed, when I entered the '#" in password browser automatically converts it into URL encoding format like '%23', want to stop that or any other solution for this issue.

form is like:

```
              labels={{
                        passwordInputLabel: 'Password',
                        passwordPlaceHolder: 'Enter password',
                        loginButtonMessage: 'Logging In'
```

Comment: Simple solution: Use other protocol than http(s)/don't use browser!;)

Comment: Just "don't worry"! The server can/*will* decode it back. (If it is conform with http;)

Comment: The `#` has a special meaning in URLs, so it has to be encoded.